# Como exportar dados do R diretamente para o sql server?

Tags: sql-server, r, exportação

Amigos, eu consumi um web service com R e agora preciso exportar estes dados diretamente para o sql server. Como faço?

Comment: Já deu uma olhada neste package? 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLServer/index.html

Comment: @ClecioNepunuceno: Qual a versão do SQL Server?

Comment: @JoséDiz , eu uso o SQL server 2014

Comment: @ClecioNepunuceno como assim exportar? Vc quer popular tabelas num banco de dados SQL Server utilizando estes dados consumidos?

Answer (score 1):

Uma das maneiras de você fazer isso é usando o pacote RODBC.

```
library(RODBC)
# Use a função odbcDriverConnect para criar uma conexão com o banco
dbhandle=odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};
                       server='your_servername';
                       database='your_database';
                       uid='your_user';
                       pwd='your_password'")

# Use a função sqlSave para salvar um data.frame em uma tabela especifica na 
# conexão criada.

sqlSave(dbhandle,'your_data_frame','you_table_name')

# Se você ainda quiser realizar a leitura de dados das tabelas disponíveis 
# no banco, use a função sqlQuery para executar uma Query.

df=sqlQuery(dbhandle,paste("SELECT * from 'your_table'"))
```